# update two tables in single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named `supply` and `equipment`. These two tables have a common field named: `IAR_NO`

Now, what I want is to update using a single *query*, all the records from both tables which have 0 in its `IAR_NO`.

what could be the best query for this?

I am currently using but does not work

```
update supply, equipment 
set supply.IAR_NO =  "9", equipment.IAR_NO= "9 " 
where equipment.IAR_NO = 0 and supply.IAR_NO = 0
```

Comment: Can't you do it in two queries but use transactions?

Comment: You need to update two tables individually in a transaction

Comment: You cannot update the keys of a table in a single query, need to do in two separated queries

Comment: It's all in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: i just want to do it that way for more elegance :), but i guess it isn't possible at all or is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible with a multi-table update, as described in the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

```
UPDATE supply a INNER JOIN equipment b ON (a.IAR_NO= b.IAR_NO)
SET a.IAR_NO =  "9" , b.IAR_NO =  "9"
WHERE equipment.IAR_NO = 0 and supply.IAR_NO = 0;
```

**Note:**

If you’re updating two tables with identical data, there’s probably a better way to design your database. Remember to keep your programming [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 6):

These are two updates that do not depend on each other (for the updating). If they need to be done together, do them in a transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE supply SET IAR_NO =  9 WHERE IAR_NO = 0;
UPDATE equipment SET IAR_NO =  9 WHERE IAR_NO = 0;
COMMIT;
```

This way it's more explicit, and I would say more elegant, because you can see what is actually updated and to what value.

Comment: For the above and if you are using php ,  do look at  mysqli_multi_query as well.