# Update two tables from union search in single form

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table with same column name. I need make search and update in single form for that's two tables.

Here is my code form search and fetch data (looklike working):

```
if(isset($_POST['Search'])) {
    $NoMohon = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Nomor']);

    //query database
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor' union SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Nomor = $rows['Nomor'];
            $Name = $rows['Name'];
            $Age = $rows['Age'];
        }
    } else {
        $output = "Data Null!";
    }
}
```

and here my code to update table :

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])) {
    $Nomor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Nomor']);

    //query database
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor' union SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");

    $Name = strtoupper($_POST['Name']);
    $Age = strtoupper($_POST['Age']);

    //NEED WORKING CODE HERE
    $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' where Nomor='$Nomor' union UPDATE table2 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' where Nomor='$Nomor'");
    header('Location: sukses.php');
}
```

If search result is value in table2, then i want update value in table2 only. If search result is value in table1, then i want update value in table1 only.

```
table1
+-------+-------------+---------+
| Nomor |   Name      |   Age   |
+-------+-------------+---------+ 
|  a1   | Supar       | 25      |
|  a2   | Rambo       | 23      |
+-------+-------------+---------+

table2
+-------+-------------+---------+
| Nomor |   Name      |   Age   |
+-------+-------------+---------+ 
|  b1   | Boneng      | 28      |
|  b2   | Dennyius    | 32      |
+-------+-------------+---------+
```

Code above for update not working. so please help me here. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You simply can't update 2 tables at once.

Comment: any solution to make search result n update from two table? in single form?

Comment: Just refer the first answer,hope it will give an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109666/update-two-tables-in-single-query-in-mysql

Comment: add example tables

Comment: **warning** your code is still vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `affected_rows` property as follows:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table2 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");
if (!$mysqli->affected_rows) { // no changes were made
  $mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)